# How do I update a foreign key relationship in entity framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework-4, timezone, foreign-keys

I have an object called Account, which has a reference to a timezone through a foreign-key relationship.
On the Account-object I can see the `TimeZone_Fk_Id` as well as the reference to both `Account.TimeZone` and `Account.TimeZoneReference`.

I am trying to update the foreign key relationship but I cannot figure out how.
I have tried all sorts of things. I have tried setting the `TimeZone_Fk_Id` directly, tried setting the `Account.TimeZone` to a new timezone, tried updating the entitykeys etc etc. But nothing seems to work. I don't get any exceptions, but when I check the timezone after I supposedly have changed it, it is still the old value.

Any help is greatly appreciated

thanks
Thomas

Comment: Can you show some code which doesn't work?

Comment: I tried all of the following:
Account.TimeZone_Fk_Id=2; (making sure that there is a timezone-record with the id 2);
tblTimeZone tz = fetch timezone from db
Account.tblTimeZone=tz; 
Account.tblTimeZoneReference.Value=tz;
Account.tblTimeZoneReference.EntityKey=tz.EntityKey;

I couldn't get none of the above to work. Everytime I try assigning a value, it doesn't update the object.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
Account account;
TimeZone timeZone;  
//Get account instance  
//Get timeZone instance to update  
account.TimeZone = timeZone;  
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I figured it out, and it was a mistake in my coding. Before saving the changes, I was comparing the timezone-setting with the original timezone-setting. In this proces, the new timezone-setting was being reset to the old one.